# java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, mysql, listview, nullpointerexception

I developed a simple listview application which gets data from the MySQL database. It displayed listview but when I'm selecting a single listview it occurs following error.

this is my xml file for single list view,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView android:id="@+id/product_label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>   
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java file,

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements FetchDataListener{
private ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
    initView(); 

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // listening to single list item on click
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {

          // selected item
          TextView txtview = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_label));
          String product = txtview.getText().toString();

          // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
          Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
          // sending data to new activity
          i.putExtra("product", product);
          startActivity(i);

      }
    });

}

private void initView() {
    // show progress dialog
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");

    String url = "http://pubbapp.comze.com/pubapp.php";
    FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask(this);
    task.execute(url);
}

@Override
public void onFetchComplete(List<Application> data) {
    // dismiss the progress dialog
    if(dialog != null)  dialog.dismiss();
    // create new adapter
    ApplicationAdapter adapter = new ApplicationAdapter(this, data);
    // set the adapter to list
    setListAdapter(adapter);        
}

@Override
public void onFetchFailure(String msg) {
    // dismiss the progress dialog
    if(dialog != null)  dialog.dismiss();
    // show failure message
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
}
}
```

this is the single list activity java file,

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SingleListItem extends Activity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item_view);

    TextView txtProduct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_label);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    // getting attached intent data
    String product = i.getStringExtra("product");
    // displaying selected product name
    txtProduct.setText(product);

}
}
```

this is the error msg,

```
11-27 00:11:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9924): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-27 00:11:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9924): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-27 00:11:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9924):     at com.sj.jsondemo.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:35)
11-27 00:11:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9924):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
11-27 00:11:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9924):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3745)
11-27 00:11:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9924):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1980)
11-27 00:11:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9924):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-27 00:11:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9924):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-27 00:11:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9924):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-27 00:11:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9924):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
11-27 00:11:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9924):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-27 00:11:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9924):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-27 00:11:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9924):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
11-27 00:11:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9924):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
11-27 00:11:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9924):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-27 00:11:59.925: I/Process(9924): Sending signal. PID: 9924 SIG: 9
```

I tried to solve this problem, but I can't find any solution for this.please help me.

Comment: can you post the stack trace.

Comment: `getListView` doesn't exist

Comment: As @Manitoba said, getListView doesn't seem to exist.
Btw, post your stack trace.

Comment: This Seems that each one is Unrelated to another. If you use ListActivity Where is your Listview in main.xml. If you use custom adapter, then where is your getview method?

Comment: `single_list_item_view` has a textview with id `product_label`. So post your adapter code and the xml that you inflate in getView

Comment: You are dereferencing a null pointer at `MainActivity.java` line 35. All this information is present in the stack trace. Duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Please support fully activity_main.xml

In you activity_main.xml which should contain ListView like below:

```
ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because, when you click on the item, it pointing to a null value, there might be no value that can be fetched from database. Please keep a breakpoint at that null pointer location and see the value its retrieving.

Comment: in my listview there are ward num(int) and date time(string) but still occurs this error.

Comment: what are the values you are getting ?? not the data types check the values

Comment: the values in my listview similar to this 1,2,.. and 2013-11-27